# How do you edit Internet Accounts in shell?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I created two IMAP accounts in Mail app.

However I had to enter two wrong email address/passwords to be able to manually set my hotmail as IMAP.

e.g. one is sdsd@erer.com

When I view them in accounts it shows it as sdsd@erer.com
I have already edited Accounts.plist and corrected but that doesn't seem to be the right place.

Where do I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed in
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.mcc.accounts

It's an XML file and it has 4 occurences of each wrong email. Updated and it works fine in Mail.app

Comment: I know it's an old answer from 2013, but for the sake of others arriving here, this file doesn't exist anymore. I didn't find the replacement though.